# Android, iOS and Windows 8 package names

Tags: android, ios, windows-8

I have a very simple question to which I assume I already know the answer (*yes*) but I can't seem to find any official confirmation that it is true.

**Are package names always unique in Android, iOS and Windows 8?**

I'm asking this since I'm developing a communication system in which I will need unique identifiers for applications written for these platforms. I'd love to use the package name if it is unique.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that they have to be unique.  Why not generate a `Guid` or a shared key and use that across these applications?

Comment: Yes that could be possible using some tricks, my main issue is there must be a unique identifier that my system can use which is known before the application is installed in my system. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No two apps may have the same package name *on the same device*.

It is possible for two developers to write apps with the same package name and distribute them through their own third party site (app stores will not allow conflicting package names).